# Submit button already clicked

Tags: php, html

I have a form that I want to submit and I check if any textbox has text so I can UPDATE something in a database.

This is the code for the form:

```html
<form action="" method="POST"/>          
CNP Nou: <input type="text" name="cnpN"/><br/> 
Nume Nou: <input type="text" name="numeN"/><br/> 
Prenume Nou: <input type="text" name="prenN"/><br/> 
Data Nasterii Noua: <input type="text" name="dataNN"/> De forma AAAA-ZZ-LL <br/> 
Sex Nou: <input type="text" name="sexN"/> F sau M <br/> 
Numar Telefon Nou: <input type="text" name="telN"/><br/> 
Adresa Noua: <input type="text" name="adrN"/><br/> 
E-mail Nou: <input type="text" name="mailN"/><br/> 
<input type="submit" value="Modifica" name="search2" class="submit" /> 
</form>
```

Then I check if the button is clicked so I can see if any textbox has text written in order to make an UPDATE in my database:

```
if (isset($_POST["search2"])) 
{
    if (!empty($_POST['cnpN']) || !empty($_POST['numeN']) || !empty($_POST['prenN']) || !empty($_POST['dataNN']) || !empty($_POST['sexN']) || !empty($_POST['telN']) || !empty($_POST['adrN']) || !empty($_POST['mailN'])) 
    {
        //php code for update
    }
}
else
{
    echo "<h4><b> Eroare! </b><h4>";
}
```

The problem is that without clicking the button I see the "Eroare!" message. If I remove that else statement and I click the button nothing happens to the database, even if I introduce something in the form.

I used the else statement just to see if that might be the problem or not.

I am looking through the code for some time and can't see the problem.
I know there are simpler ways to check the completed textboxes but I'm new to php and I thought it's easier this way.

Comment: Your code is outputting 'Eroare' because, initially, you don't have post request input

Comment: I knew that. I wanted to see where the code stopped working, that's why I used it

Comment: please don't give negative points to every answer. Also, if you knew that, you wouldn't place it there

Comment: I should have been more specific, I'm sorry. I did not give any negative points

Comment: I apologize too. So main thing is that you don't have any request data set initially on load. And then, it will always output 'Eroar', so you need to skip this part. And put it as part after input validation block. As explained below.

Comment: @niklaz I gave the negative points because none of the original answers explained clearly why "Eroare!" was appearing. After that, everyone edited their answers so the voting worked as intended.

Comment: @JoshJ, thanks for explaining, but see revisions of my answer https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54052619/revisions. You will notice that in first version of answer I have explained why 'Eroare' was appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submit button is not already clicked , but your code is outputting 'Eroare' because, initially, you don't have set any post data on page load, including `search2`. So you don't need `else` part of conditional unless you mark that an error occurred, but within the `if(isset($_POST["search2"])){}` block. 
Otherwise, it will always output the 'Eroare'.

You first need to validate your form data, then to throw the error if any of form data doesn't fulfill the conditions.

About validation process, you would either need to implement some existing validation libraries or to extend your conditional to check for specific data, specific validation requirements.

Some of them would be required (not empty), some of them would require constrained/limited values from a list ( like gender field ), some would require number value validation ( phone ), an email field would require email value  validation.

Also, you are missing the part for DB insertion.

Simplified code without advanced validation would be like this:

```
  <?php

$post_search2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'search2'); //filter_input returns empty if input not set, and it is useful to filter and validate specific values;
if(!empty($post_search2))
{

    $form_values = array('cnpN', 'numeN', 'prenN', 'dataNN', 'sexNN', 'telN', 'adrN', 'mailN'); //I have placed it in array to avoid having large code and simplify checks through iteration

    $parsed_data = array();
    foreach($form_values as $form_value){
        $value = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $form_value);
        if(!empty($value)){ //update parsed data only if form data is not empty
            $parsed_data[$form_value] = $value;
        }

    }
    //so if any of data is filled, do the updates
    //this actually does same as  !empty($_POST['cnpN']) || !empty($_POST['numeN']) || !empty($_POST['prenN']) && ... 
    //  if you would require all data filled, check if count($parsed_data) === count($form_values) and that actually does same as this actually does same as  !empty($_POST['cnpN']) && !empty($_POST['numeN']) &&  !empty($_POST['prenN']) && ...
    //
    if(count($parsed_data) > 0){
        //php code for update

    }else{
        echo "<h4><b> Eroare! </b><h4>";
    }


}

?>

<form action="" method="POST">
CNP Nou: <input type="text" name="cnpN"/><br/>
Nume Nou: <input type="text" name="numeN"/><br/>
Prenume Nou: <input type="text" name="prenN"/><br/>
Data Nasterii Noua: <input type="text" name="dataNN"/> De forma AAAA-ZZ-LL <br/>
Sex Nou: <input type="text" name="sexN"/> F sau M <br/>
Numar Telefon Nou: <input type="text" name="telN"/><br/>
Adresa Noua: <input type="text" name="adrN"/><br/>
E-mail Nou: <input type="text" name="mailN"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Modifica" name="search2" class="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The else clause belongs on the if not empty conditional.

When you first load the php script, there is no POST data present. That is expected since it is a GET request. This is why the initial conditional is false and the error message appears. POST will never be set on an HTTP GET request.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working perfectly normal, output is showing because in the begining the "form" is not submitted and "if" it is not submitted then "else" should work and "else" is working. if you don't want it to be shown then you can remove else.it will work fine, also try not to end the form tag early

instead of

`<form action="" method="POST"/>`

use this

```
<form action="" method="POST">     `
```

Comment: sadly this was not the problem

Comment: you should consider the answer one more time

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the close tag from the form tag

ie, change `<form action="" method="POST"/>` to `<form action="" method="POST">`

If it doesn't solve your issue then use the following code snippet,

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">          
CNP Nou: <input type="text" name="cnpN"/><br/> 
Nume Nou: <input type="text" name="numeN"/><br/> 
Prenume Nou: <input type="text" name="prenN"/><br/> 
Data Nasterii Noua: <input type="text" name="dataNN"/> De forma AAAA-ZZ-LL <br/> 
Sex Nou: <input type="text" name="sexN"/> F sau M <br/> 
Numar Telefon Nou: <input type="text" name="telN"/><br/> 
Adresa Noua: <input type="text" name="adrN"/><br/> 
E-mail Nou: <input type="text" name="mailN"/><br/> 
<input type="submit" value="Modifica" name="search2" class="submit" /> 
</form>
```

PHP Code

```
if(isset($_POST["search2"]))  
      if(!empty($_POST['cnpN']) || !empty($_POST['numeN']) || !empty($_POST['prenN']) || !empty($_POST['dataNN']) || !empty($_POST['sexN']) || !empty($_POST['telN']) || !empty($_POST['adrN']) || !empty($_POST['mailN']))
      {
             //php code for update
      }
```